# How do I update my current version of Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to upgrade from version `1.3.4` to `v1.4`, but I do not see anything in the installation or getting started guide regarding updating a current installation. I know I could just do a fresh install of Elixir, but what is the standard way of upgrading to a higher version?

Comment: What OS are you running Elixir on? Are you using something like Homebrew or Chocolatey?

Comment: Windows. I believe I just used the Windows Installer.

Comment: I can think of two things you could do.  
1) Like you said, just get an updated binary and install that. Or,  
2)The way I prefer is to make use of Chocolatey to install Elixir. Chocolatey is Windows' package management tool. The nice thing about this is that you can update to the latest version of Elixir or install specific versions.  
Here is the Chocolatey page for Elixir: https://chocolatey.org/packages/Elixir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows environment, the most preferred way is to make use of Chocolatey to install Elixir. Chocolatey is Windows' package management tool. The nice thing about this is that you can update to the latest version of Elixir or install specific versions.

Here is the Chocolatey page for Elixir: https://chocolatey.org/packages/Elixir

Answer (score 0):

For those not using chocolatey: Go to the [elixir install page](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html) , download the web installer for windows and execute the installer.

During installation it will ask if you want to replace your current installation of both elixir and erlang.

As a sidenote if you want to update phoenix too just run this command in a cmd window:

```
mix archive.install hex phx_new X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X is the phoenix version you want to update. At the time of writing this comment it is 1.5.7